# Identify lines where word occurs in a text and save the lines in a list

Tags: python, string, text

I'm currently trying to scan a text, identify the lines in which the word occurs multiple times and save the lines in a list. If the word does not appear in a text, an empty list should be returned.

This is what i have so far;

```
def line_number(text,word):
    
   
    with open(text) as file: 
        lines = file.readlines() 
    for line_number, line in enumerate(lines,1): 
        if word in line:  
            print(f'{word} is in the line {line_number}')
                  
        else: 
            pass
    print("None")
```

At this point, I can print out the lines where a word occurs, but I need a way to save the lines

Comment: How many times does it need to appear for it to be saved?

Comment: Instead of printing the values, add them to a list. At the end of the method, open a file in write mode (`open("out.txt", "w")`), iterate over your list and write each element to your file.

Comment: @FreddyMcloughlan as long as the word appears in a text, the line number should be stored.  For example, if the word 'python' appears 5 times in a text, the final list should show the lines of the text where the word 'python' appeared

Answer (score 0):

You can append a `tuple` `(line, count)` for each `line` in `lines`:

```py
def line_number(text, word):
    with open(text) as file:
        lines = file.readlines()

    lst = [(x.strip(), x.count(word)) for x in lines if x.strip()]

    return lst
```

---

A test file, with `word='test'`:

```
test test test

test sdf sdfuih test
asdlkj
123
```

returns

```
[('test test test', 3),
 ('test sdf sdfuih test', 2),
 ('asdlkj', 0),
 ('123', 0)]
```

You can then sort or max your occurrences with:

```
>>> x = line_number("file2.txt", "test")
# Sorted
>>> sorted(x, key=lambda a: a[0], reverse=True)
[('test test test', 3),
 ('test sdf sdfuih test', 2),
 ('asdlkj', 0),
 ('123', 0),
# Max
>>> max(x, key=lambda a: a[0])
('test test test', 3)
```

---

Or you can save the line number, instead of the `line`

```
# i + 1 means first line is 1
lst = [(i+1, x.count(word)) for i, x in enumerate(lines) if x.strip()]
```

---

**Edit**: as requested by your comment, this just gets the line number for occurrences of the `word`:

```py
# returns [1, 3] for test file above
lst = [i+1 for i, x in enumerate(lines) if word in x]
```

Comment: Thanks @Freddy. Do i need to initiate a empty list (1st) and then append all the lines to that list? Because this approach did not work so far

Comment: No, why didn't it work? what happened?

Answer (score 0):

Seems like an SEO based functionality. Maybe what you can do is save the lines very much after the print statement, maybe write that line and close in separate files because you may need it, and assign a trigger to work it, where each line constitutes address from the first line.

Comment: Yup, this is what I'm trying to do. Save the lines in a list

Comment: Then it is pretty much simple, you can simply .read() those lines, then save them in a file, and access it whenever in future you require it. When done you can even delete them.

Answer (score 0):

Using `enumerate`, you just need to create an empty list and append it.

```
def line_number(text, word):
    my_list = []
    with open(text) as f:
        lines = f.readlines()

    for id, line in enumerate(lines):
        if word in line:
            #print(f"{word} --> {id}")
            my_list.append(id)
    return(my_list)


text = "tes_test_text.txt"
word = "stack"

print(line_number(text, word))
```